# How to avoid inheritance of .css in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a react application. The `App.js` fragment is as follow:

```
import ServiceManual from './components/pages/ServiceManual'
import './App.css'; 

const App = () => {
      return (
            <>
                  <Router>
                              <Switch>
                                    <Route path='/ServiceManual' exact component={ServiceManual} />
                                    <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
                              </Switch>
                  </Router>
            </>
      )
};
```

The `ServiceManual` component contains it's own `ServiceManual.module.css`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../App.css';
import './ServiceManual.module.css';

export default function ServiceManual() {
    return <Container fluid className="mainPage">
....
```

Now, my problem is that some definitions contained into the `ServiceManual.module.css` influence the content of my `Home` page.

It looks like the import of the component in the `App.js` build an enormous container where all the imported definition will finish.

I found on the internet the suggestion to name `xxx.module.css` instead of `xxx.css` a .css file that has to be used just in the module where it is imported. But this is not true.

When I open the browser debugger on my home page I see some .css definitions (defined in `xxx.module.css`) that shouldn't be there and that change the way my homepage is displayed.

Has anyone a hint, please?

Answer (score 0):

The truth is, all CSS files are included in the page as long as they are imported, no matter where.
If you need different styles for different elements, give them unique class names and handle them by their class names in their various CSS scripts.

Comment: Well, this is true for components I develop, but if you use an external component (ie: component about privacy or cookies developed by third parties) this is practically impossible ....